# How to connect cPanel Git Version Control to a private repository?

Tags: github, cpanel

I'd like to connect my hosting's cPanel to a private repository in GitHub.
I've tried to do so using 5 simple steps but it doesn't work, can you kindly assist?

I have:

1. Created a cPanel key:

   [image: Manage SSH Keys]
2. Authorized and View/Downloaded it:

   [image: authorized + view/download]


   [image: View or Download]
3. Opened the GitHub private repository's setting, pasted the copied key into Deploy Keys (including write access) and hit Add Key (likewise in BitBucket's Access Keys):

   [image: Deploy Keys]
4. Opened the GitHub private repository's homepage, clicked Code, chose SSH and copied the result (likewise with BitBucket's Clone button):

   [image: Code SSH]
5. Went back to cPanel's Git Version Control, pasted the URL into **Clone URL**...and got an error:

> **Error**: (XID bvp8gj) “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported
> error code “128” when it ended: Warning: Permanently added
> 'github.com,[IP Address]' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
> from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access
> rights and the repository exists.

[image: Code SSH fails]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's **all about step 1**:

1. It **cannot** be done via UI since it must **not** have a password/passphrase, as confirmed [by GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) and [by cPanel](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/#generate-an-ssh-key).
2. It must **not** be named anything other than the default `id_rsa/id_rsa.pub` (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74365447)).
   The thing is cPanel does point to using Terminal for this...only to give **incorrect** instructions to rename it, which fails the whole process.

In other words, step 1 must be:

1. Open cPanel's Terminal and type `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`.
   [image: cPanel Terminal with ssh-keygen]

Note it's not just removing `-f filename`, but there's also no need for `-C "username@example.com"` since the Terminal way adds it automatically anyway.

The rest of the steps remain the same.

**Of course, this limitation of only 1 single filename for the entire GitHub means you can't use Deploy Keys to connect to more than one private repository.**